# UnsupportedOperationException in gremlin "by step with range" for more than one element

Tags: pagination, gremlin, amazon-neptune, tinkerpop3, gremlin-java

```
g.V().hasLabel('employee').fold().as("emp", "count")
.select("emp", "count")
.by(range(local, 0, 2).elementMap())
.by(count(local));
```

The above query is working fine when the range interval is 1 (OR) total number of return vertex is 1.

If it has more than one vertex or the range interval is increased, getting the `UnsupportedOperationException` exception.  How to solve?

The same query works without `elementMap()`, however, it's needed in application just vertex id is not helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UnsupportedOperation` exception is because you are creating essentially a list of vertices when the `range` yields more than one result. The full error is actually going to be something like:

```java
{
  "requestId": "c98008d3-104e-4972-9d9c-c78186646cba",
  "code": "UnsupportedOperationException",
  "detailedMessage": "java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Element"
}
```

Which gives us a clue. The query expected an element, like a vertex or an edge but instead got a list of vertices.

When the `range` is from 0 to 2, the result will be of the form:

````java
{'emp': [v[3741], v[3742]], 'count': 7}```
````

You will need to do something like

```java
 by(range(local, 0, 2).unfold().elementMap().fold())
```

for the query to work correctly.

Note that the query can be rewritten using `project`:

```java
g.V().hasLabel('employee').fold().
  project("emp", "count").
    by(range(local, 0, 2).unfold().elementMap().fold()).
    by(count(local))
```